# Handle summation of big binomials in Python

Tags: python, math, computation

I need to compute this formula:

[image: Summation]

It is an approximation of this integral

[image: Integral]

but it doesn't matter, actually I just want to compute the value of Figure [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fi12W.gif) with **PYTHON**, that's what the topic concerns.

K, alpha and sigma are fixed values within a single computation, usually:

- 0 <= k <= 99;
- alpha = 3;
- sigma = 2.

Below is how I am trying to compute such summation in python:

```
import decimal
from scipy.special import binom

def residual_time_mean(alpha, sigma=2, k=1):
    prev_prec = decimal.getcontext().prec
    D = decimal.Decimal
    decimal.getcontext().prec = 128

    a = float(alpha)
    s = float(sigma)
    sum1 = 0.0
    sum2 = 0.0
    sumD1 = D(0.0)
    sumD2 = D(0.0)

    for i in range(1, k + 1):
        sum1 += binom(k, i) * ((-1) ** (i + 1)) * (s / ((a - 1) * i - 1.0))
        sum2 += binom(k, i) * ((-1) ** (i + 1)) * s / ((a - 1) * i - 1.0)
        sumD1 += D(binom(k, i)) * (D(-1.0) ** (D(i) + D(1.0))) * (D(s) / ((D(a) - D(1.0)) * D(i) - D(1.0)))
        sumD2 += D(binom(k, i)) * (D(-1.0) ** (D(i) + D(1.0))) * D(s) / ((D(a) - D(1.0)) * D(i) - D(1.0))

    decimal.getcontext().prec = prev_prec

    return sum1, sum2, float(sumD1), float(sumD2)
```

Running

```
for k in [0, 1, 2, 4, 8, 20, 50, 99]:
    print("k={} -> {}".format(k, residual_time_mean(3, 2, k)))
```

the outcome is:

```
k=0 -> (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
k=1 -> (2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0)
k=2 -> (3.3333333333333335, 3.3333333333333335, 3.3333333333333335, 3.3333333333333335)
k=4 -> (5.314285714285714, 5.314285714285714, 5.314285714285714, 5.314285714285714)
k=8 -> (8.184304584304588, 8.184304584304583, 8.184304584304584, 8.184304584304584)
k=20 -> (13.952692275798238, 13.952692275795965, 13.95269227579524, 13.95269227579524)
k=50 -> (23.134878809207617, 23.13390225415814, 23.134078892910786, 23.134078892910786)
k=99 -> (265412075330.96634, 179529505602.9507, 17667813427.20196, 17667813427.20196)
```

You can see that starting from `k=8` the results are different.

Making a multiplication before a division leads results of `sum1` and `sum2` to diverge a lot for k=99 for instance.

```
sum1 += binom(k, i) * ((-1) ** (i + 1)) * (s / ((a - 1) * i - 1.0))
sum2 += binom(k, i) * ((-1) ** (i + 1)) * s / ((a - 1) * i - 1.0)
```

With decimal this problem doesn't occur but the result is not correct at all.

### Computing the summation on WolframAlpha

#### for k = `99`

([Here is the link for the computation on WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20(binom(99,i)%20*%20(-1)%5E(i%2B1)*%20(2%2F(2i-1)),%20i%3D1%20to%2099)). It gives **33.3159488**(...) while for my python function it is 17667813427.20196. I trust WolframAlpha since it makes something like symbolic computation, indeed it also returns the real value in form of a fraction.

#### for other k

Approximation problems (e.g. the value computed by Wolfram is different from the one computed in python by an order of magnitude of 10^0 or more) starts occurring from k~=60.

Moreover computing the integral (Figure [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CaHGl.gif)) with `scipy.integrate` leads to similar approximation errors.

## The question:

Do you have any suggestion to handle this computation? Increasing decimal precision doesn't seem to be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you involve a `numpy` function here, and why you are converting to `float` objects. Really, for this formula, if your inputs are always integers, then simply stick with `int` and `fractions.Fraction` and your answers will always be *exact*. It is easy enough to implement your own `binom` function:

```
In [8]: def binom(n, k):
    ...:     return (
    ...:         factorial(n)
    ...:         // (factorial(k)*factorial(n-k))
    ...:     )
    ...:
```

Note, I used integer division: `//`. And finally, your summation:

```
In [9]: from fractions import Fraction
    ...: def F(k, a, s):
    ...:     result = Fraction(0, 1)
    ...:     for i in range(1, k+1):
    ...:         b = binom(k, i)*pow(-1, i+1)
    ...:         x = Fraction(s, (a-1)*i - 1)
    ...:         result += b*x
    ...:     return result
    ...:
```

And the results:

```
In [10]: F(99, 3, 2)
Out[10]: Fraction(47372953498165579239913571130715220654368322523193013011418, 1421930192463933435386372127473055337225260516259631545875)
```

Which seems correct based on wolfram-alpha...

Note, if say, `alpha` can be a non-integer, you could use `decimal.Decimal` for arbitary-precision floating point operations:

```
In [17]: from decimal import Decimal
     ...: def F(k, a, s):
     ...:     result = Decimal('0')
     ...:     for i in range(1, k+1):
     ...:         b = binom(k, i)*pow(-1, i+1)
     ...:         x = Decimal(s) / Decimal((a-1)*i - 1)
     ...:         result += b*x
     ...:     return result
     ...:

In [18]: F(99, 3, 2)
Out[18]: Decimal('33.72169506311642881389682714')
```

Let's up the precision:

```
In [20]: import decimal

In [21]: decimal.getcontext().prec
Out[21]: 28

In [22]: decimal.getcontext().prec = 100

In [23]: F(99, 3, 2)
Out[23]: Decimal('33.31594880623309576443774363783112352607484321721989160481537847749994248174570647797323789728798446')
```

Comment: Yes, manually computing the binomial (with **integer division** between numerator and denominator) gives the value I am seeking for. The summation I want to calculate is part of another equation's denominator used to compute the slope of a line so, amongst the four values I was computing, I will keep the one calculated using Decimal, just like you are suggesting (also since alpha and sigma are real values). Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I've discovered the problem by myself:

Executing `scipy.special.binom(99,50)` gives

```
5.044567227278209e+28
```

while calculating binomial (99,50) on WolframAlpha gives

```
5.0445672272782096667406248628e+28
```

There is an absolute difference with an order of magnitude of 10^12.

That's why, for sure, results of python function are unreliable for high values of k. So I need to change how the binomial is computed.

Comment: This is a numpy function. It always returns a fixed-size numpy floating point type. Floating point numbers are imprecise, and of fixed size. The formula for a binomial coefficient is simple to implement yourself. Just `import math` and use `math.factorial` for speed

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `mpmath`, which [supports binomial functions and allows to define arbitrary precision](https://mpmath.readthedocs.io/en/latest/functions/gamma.html#binomial-coefficients).  For your example it returns for instance 50445672272782096667406248628.0

Comment: @Mr.T well, sure, but this is pretty simple to implement using Python  built-ins...

Comment: Mr. T, You're right, using scipy function is not that good here. I should rather use one from another library, with bigger or arbitrary precision, or, more simply, implement it by myself like @juanpa.arrivillaga suggests in his reply. I've already changed to a custom implementation of binomial function and everything is working as it was supposed to do. Thank you all :)