# Infinite series converges to wrong value after a certain abcissa

Tags: python

I need to have the Bessel functions of the first kind in a part of my code

[image: Bessel function]

Below I show how I implemented it so you can get the same error as I did:

```
def bessel(nu, x, tol):
    if nu%1 != 0:
        print("nu has to be an integer")
        sys.exit()
    J = 0.0
    dJ_perc = tol + 1
    m = -1
    while dJ_perc > tol:
        J_old = J
        m = m+1
        J += (-1)**m*(x**(2*m+nu))/((2**(2*m+nu))*(math.factorial(m))*(math.factorial(m+nu)))
        if m > 4 and J_old == 0: # minimum number of terms and avoids                                                 
                                 # division by 0
            dJ_perc = tol/2
        elif m > 4 and J_old != 0:
            dJ_perc = abs((J-J_old)/J_old*100)
    return J, m

J0 = np.array([])
J1 = np.array([])
m0 = np.array([]) # number of iterations for each Bessel function value 
m1 = np.array([]) # calculated. Just to help fining the problem. To be 
                  # deleted later.
tol_J_lam = 0.01  # tolerance to identify convergence of J
lam = np.linspace (0,40,121,endpoint=True)

for i in range(0,lam.size):
    J0 = np.append(J0,bessel(0,lam[i],tol_J_lam)[0])
    J1 = np.append(J1,bessel(1,lam[i],tol_J_lam)[0])
    m0 = np.append(m0,bessel(0,lam[i],tol_J_lam)[1]) # just to help finding
    m1 = np.append(m1,bessel(1,lam[i],tol_J_lam)[1]) # the problem. To be 
                                                     # deleted later.
fig3, ax3 = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
ax3.plot(lam, J0,color='blue',linestyle='-.')
ax3.plot(lam, J1,color='red',linestyle=':')
ax3.legend(['J0','J1'],loc=0)
ax3.grid(True)

fig4, ax4 = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
ax4.plot(lam, m0,color='m',linestyle='-.')
ax4.plot(lam, m1,color='y',linestyle='--')
```

As can be seen in the generated plot the result is right until x=35 approximately, but then it starts to behave weirdly and I couldn't find out why.
[Obtained plot of Bessel functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNVYI.png)

I suspect it can be caused by rounding errors, so I tried to split de summation of J into more code lines. I also tried to work with `decimal.Decimal` as suggested here:
[Handle summation of big binomials in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50601513/handle-summation-of-big-binomials-in-python)
for the variable J but the same problem occurred.
If I reduce the tolerance for convergence nothing changes and the number of iterations keeps the same. Now I have no idea of how to fix it.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You are missing that `x^n` term I guess

Comment: @MohilPatel , I included this term inside the sum operator. That's why the exponent of x is `2*m+nu` instead of only `2*m` .

Comment: Dont know what is wrong, but if the point is just have the Bessel function, and not implement one, you can find it here  https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/special.html

Comment: @PedroFaria Yes. But when I remove it and multiply outside loop, I got something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaWed.png). Maybe it is affecting convergence

Comment: @MohilPatel, I didn't understand what you meant. The image you sent has the same problem as mine. And I tried to take this term out of the summation and obtained the same problem also :/

Comment: @Filipe,  I'm a begginer with Python so I didn't know about this built in function. It solved the problem, though I'm still curious about the problem in my code. But thanks a lot! Should I delete the question, since the solution was kind of  dumb?

Comment: I am new here too, but i dont think you should delete your question, since we still dont know what cause the problem, and maybe there is something useful to learn about that.